# Figures attribution index

Tags: bibliographies, floats, licensing

I am creating a document with photographs taken from others, so I have to include the attributions. I would like to have a "figures bibliography" similar to the one generated by `\printbibliography` from the `biblatex` package. For each image the index should show at least:

- the name of the author;
- the license the image is released under;
- a link to the source of the image (if present).

The images should obviously be identifiable, at least the ones with a `\caption`. Best thing would be if it was possible to refer to the images with the number of the page they are on if no caption is provided.

For example:

> ### Figures attributions
>
> **1.1: foo bar** John Doe [CC-BY-SA]. URL: https://example.com/foo
>
> **p. 13** Numerio Negidio [CC-0]. URL: https://example.com/lorem

Is there an easy way to do that - probably a package?